# How to specify a browser to use for debugging in Visual C# 2008 Express?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xbap

With recent events with vulnerability found in WPF browser plugin and Firefox forcing a block on it, I can't seem to find a setting in Visual C# 2008 Express Edition that would allow me to run/debug my XBAP project in Internet Explorer without having to switch my default browser to IE. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's a web project that option isn't available, at least not for the Express editions of Visual Studio. There's a "Browse With..." context menu option for the Solution Explorer, but I'm pretty sure that's just for web projects, maybe you can try the Web Developer Express edition, but I don't know it has the support for WPF you need... err.. maybe you should just get the Professional Edition...

Comment: Just what I thought. I have a license for Pro but just wanted to finish a project with Express. And anyway that's a pretty lame reason to switch to Pro when Express does all you currently need ;) Btw, are you sure you can set a custom browser to run in Pro?

Comment: Yeah sure, the only tricky part is that you'll have to right-click a 'browsable' item in the solution explorer for the menu option to show. The option is called "Browse With" and it will allow you to chose a browser, but it will also let you change which one is the default.

Comment: I'm certain the option exists in all the editions of Visual Studio as well as the Express ones. But I have noticed some features missing from the Express editions that I sometimes want to have, for that reason I've stopped using them, and stick with pro.